# Bootstrap media vs pulls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following header I am trying to code responsively using Twitter Bootstrap:

[image]

Now for the purple menu bar I am going to use a navbar. However, for the content above, I am really trying to determine the best approach. I am stuck between using media or pull-left and pull-right. I am really unsure what the best approach for this would be.

Any recommendations as to the proper way of coding this using Bootstraps built in classes would be appreciated. Please note that only the logo would be an image, everything else would use fonts and font icons.

Comment: Why pull? I don't know what are you trying. explain better your problem and add that you are trying so far. Otherwise this should be closed by offtopic causes. (Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) for the content above.

The only thing here where the Media object suits is the "phone number and email" part.

For "follow us" use nested rows/cols.

It would have been a lot easier to help you if you had provided us code too.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you should build a row with different columns. See my example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Lef content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>middle content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>Right content</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```